# Extracting data from NDVI false color image in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have a  NDVI **`false color image`**

There the NDVI <-1,+1> range was re-colored by a false color LUT.

I need to extract back the NDVI index data from the false color pixelmap.

**How to make MATLAB** access & reconstruct the NDVI index data, which should finally have again values from the range -1 to 1?

---

Side notes:

I only have MATLAB at my disposal for this.

Comment: I have tried to read the image in as both indexed image and rgb image and I still cant see the aray that should have values between -1 and 1, the NDVi scal. Please look at Wikipedia entry for details about NDVI scale.

Comment: Your image is not lookung that way. The `.java` source-code (that got erased from the *Side notes*) was listed to show you the idea behind the process of False-color cLUT-forward-conversion. Thus your false-colour file is not having NDVI values directly, but their multi-channel ( RGB / RGBa / * ) false-recoloured visualisation. You need to convert that from `RGB/RGBa`-colourSpace into `float`-indexSpace

Answer (score 0):

### Import file first

Depends on your False-colour `file-type`

```
% DEPENDS ON YOUR FILE FORMAT _______________________________________
%
% MAY READ-IN .TIF/.

I = imread('False_coloured_(NDVI2RGB)_converted_SatIMAGE.tif');

% MIGHT NEED A MORE COMPLEX fileInput AS FROM MULTIBAND SOURCE
%
% = multibandread( ... );
%
% DEPENDS ON YOUR FILE FORMAT _______________________________________
```

Check the actual structure if `I` after `imread()` / `mutlibandread()`

### Reverse-conversion from `[cLUT]` colourSpace -> float NDVI-indexSpace

This sounds simple, but without a proper a-priori knowledge of the `cLUT` **forward**-conversion, you have to guess.

8-bit gray images have a simplest way ( while a proper care has to be taken too ).

It is possible to de-map the Image range of values [0..255] in theory, [0..250] in practice ( sometime 251-means water, or 253-means a fill, **for details kindly check carefully your Image-vendor's documentation** rather than asking volunteers here to read Wikipedia et al )

### The issue is not the RGB conversion, but the `[cLUT]` colourMap used

You easily browse and inspect the Image RGB colourSpace values

```
falseColourRED   = I(:,:,1);
falseColourGREEN = I(:,:,2);
falseColourBLUE  = I(:,:,3);
```

The goal is to guess the reverse-translation.

Initial guess to move from [RGB]-> NDVI via **reverse**-mapping onto

a `linspace( -1.0, 1.0, nUniqueRgbClrTripletsFoundInTheIMAGE )`

**fails** the more "wilder" / the more "exotic" a false-colouring process `[cLUT]` colourMap was in the **forward**-conversion, so as to emphasise some specific agricultural phenomena.

**So you need to know** the original **forward**-conversion `[cLUT]` mapping used.

### Sample `[cLUT]` colourMap differences

[image: Sample cLUT colourMAP]
[image: Sample cLUT colourMAP]
[image: Sample cLUT colourMAP]

So looking top-to-bottom you hopefully visually realise the **reverse**-conversion issue

```
Vendor specific [cLUT]-Forward-conversion mapping NDVI-indexSpace->colorSpace ambiguity:
------------------------------------------------------------------------
[+1.0]->Red
[+1.0]->DarkBrown
[+1.0]->Violet
[+1.0]->DarkBlue
[+1.0]->DarkGreen

------------------------------------------------------------------------
colorSpace -> NDVI-indexSpace [cLUT]-Reverse-conversion ambiguity:
------------------------------------------------------------------------
                        [Red]->+1.0
                        [Red]->+0.8
                        ...
                        ..
                        .
```